# cannot scroll all the way down when soft keyboard is visible

Tags: java, android, layout, keyboard

I have an android activity with search box at the top of its layout.

below it there is a listView with X items.

When the user insert some text to the search box, the soft keyboard appears.

Then keyboard overlaps the list and hides the bottom items.

A scroll appears in the list. The user can scroll down to reveal lower items

but will never be able to see the most bottom 2-3 items

(hidden by the keyboard.

Is there a way to enable full scroll or is it planed that way assuming the user won't search text and scroll to the lease relevant results?

Comment: i think you want to use scrollview in layout...(where you used searchbox and listview)..i know the listview auto scroll but it will help you when keyboard hide the half of the screen